# Intellij Python plugin syntax highlighting of Java class import in Jython

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, jython

I'm using the latest IntelliJ IDEA Community IDE with the latest Python plugin to edit Jython code.  In the IDE I can edit and run pure Python code using the Jython runtime installed on the machine.

However when I import a java class, the IntelliJ IDE marks the elements in the import statement as "unresolved references".  But the code itself correctly runs.

[image]

Is there anyway to convince the IntelliJ syntax highlighting that this is valid Jython code?

Comment: You can suppress this particular unresolved reference error from alt+enter menu, but I suggest submitting an issue to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues as this is either a bug or a missing feature.

Comment: @AndreyResler I really hate suppressing errors.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to my issue was to install the [Jython Helper](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7362-jythonhelper/) plugin (also on [Github](https://github.com/kaneg/JythonHelper)).  This plugin creates stub files for any Java class that is referenced by a Jython program.   Once the stub files are created then the red lines go away.   But as I have already proved, the red lines are not an impediment to actually running the code.

Note that I am not associated with this plugin, I only discovered it after posting my question.